# Recovering wallet using BIP32/wordlist/.priv file

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-recovery, recover-private-key, msigna

I was using Msigna but it's having issues connecting to the localhost (Running updated bitcoinqt). I sent coins to my old account without waiting for sync (noob move) but now I'm unable to access the wallet.

Can anyone help me with migrating from msigna to another wallet? I'm able to download my private key but unable to actually find out what it is. I do have the master key BIP32 and the wordlist associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation paths for BIP32 will be different. The easiest way to migrate is to sync mSIGNA and send all the coins to an address generated by the other wallet.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the BIP39 wordlist, you can switch to any BIP39 compatible wallet easily.  I prefer Bitpay's Copay wallet (http://copay.io/) - it's cross platform so you can find a version for whatever OS you use.  Mycelieum (https://wallet.mycelium.com/) is another option, although I'm not as familiar with it.

With Copay, you would simply go to the menu and select `Add Wallet` -> `Import Wallet` and then type in your BIP39 wordlist.

Comment: BIP32 does not have any word list feature. I believe you may be talking about BIP39 instead.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I've updated the answer to be accurate.